# cv2.VideoCapture freezes my whole computer

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with cv2.VideoCapture() method. Whenever i want to work with some video, it just freezes my whole computer and only thing I can do is to turn off computer manually with button. I just got new computer and that was never happening on the old one. So I tried to simplify the problem and just grabbed some example code for video capture and got the same behavior, computer got all frozen up and i could do nothing but turn it off manually.

I am using Python 3.6 with PyCharm and my new computer is Intel NUC 7i3BNK.

I really couldn't find any solution for this. Thanks for your answers!

My example code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cap = cv.VideoCapture("mizuno-cam1.mp4")
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # if frame is read correctly ret is True
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, problem solved, I just reinstalled all the dependencies for opencv, installed FFmpeg package and reinstalled opencv. I don't know what specific operation helped me to solve this problem, but if you have same problem just try to do the all :)

Thanks for reading i hope this post will help somebody who is experiencing similar problem/